# REST API: Setting Item Quantity / Need to Get Current Reserved Quantity of an item

Tags: magento2.3, api, rest-api

Working on using the Magento 2.3 Rest API to set the Quantity of an item available based on a separate datastore. I realize that the formula for getting the Total Salable quantity is based on the reserved quantity and the total stock. Because of this we need to add the reserved quantity from Magento into our quantity number that we push via the api.

I've looked over the api documentation a bunch and I have not found a way to get the total reserved quantity of the item. With out adding the total reserved quantity to the quantity that we are seeing to the Rest API we will have a resulting salable quantity lower than what is available for sale.

Has anyone been able to find a way to get the current reserved quantity for the items via the REST API?